# Instant Messaging App Mechanism

Tags: android

I've read many inconclusive articles regarding the mechanisms used by IM apps for mobile devices and I'd like someone to please clarify this for me. Do all IM apps for mobile devices simply use SMS? If not, how does the real-time communication between devices work? Is there an intermediate server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most cellular carriers do not allow sockets which accept connections (servers) to run on mobile devices.  As far as I understand, IM services with large numbers of users (e.g. MSN, AIM, Yahoo, ICQ, Skype) rely on a server to transfer the messages between mobile clients.  I make this conclusion because each client must log into the server in order to use the IM service; they offer no way to do peer-to-peer connections and avoid logging in to the server.

Comment: So is the communication between mobile device and server (and between server and mobile device) accomplished via SMS? or some other means? Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: No, SMS is not involved in normal instant messaging.  IM uses socket communication.

Comment: In other words, *yes*, there is an intermediate server.

Answer (score 0):

No, SMS is never used for what's considered instant messaging by most. If you want to develop instant messaging app, you'll need a server and push notifications. I recommend [Parse Push](https://parse.com/products/push), but you should take a look at [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), too. If nothing else, it will give you an idea on how this stuff works.